# How does the c++ linker choose which definition of a class to link into an executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker

I have a class `foo` in a header file `foo.h` that prints differently based on whether or not a macro is defined.

foo.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
    void print()
    {
#ifdef GOOD
        std::cout << "good\n";
#else
        std::cout << "bad\n";
#endif
    }
};
```

Then I have two cpp files, `good.cpp` and `bad.cpp` that include `foo.h` - one that defines the macro, and the other that doesn't.

good.cpp

```
#define GOOD
#include "foo.h"

void good()
{
    foo f;
    f.print();
}
```

bad.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

void bad()
{
    foo f;
    f.print();
}
```

Finally, in my main program, I have this

main.cpp

```
extern void good();
extern void bad();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    good();
    bad();
}
```

Using VC++ 2013, this prints the following output

```
bad
bad
```

Why did the linker choose the 'bad' version of `foo`? Is there a way to force the linker to choose a particular version of `foo`?

Comment: 1) There is no C++ linker. 2) Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) "Other violations, particularly those that span translation units, are not required to be diagnosed." ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The linker has multiple definitions to choose from.  It flips a coin and picks one.  It random number generator is however not cryptographically secure.

Comment: @PeterHuene: Section 3.2 "One Definition Rule", Paragraph 3, explicitly excludes inline functions. Since member function defined within the class declaration are implicitly inline, `print()` is an inline function. So which part of the Rule _is_ violated by the program?

Comment: @matz Inline functions can have multiple definitions (i.e. there is a definition in multiple translation units because it is inline), *but the definitions must be identical*.  This violates that rule.

Comment: @PeterHuene I see, thanks. Just for completeness: I was looking at an old version of the standard before, so my previous comment actually referred to Paragraph 4, not 3. And the requirement that the definitions in multiple translation units are identical is Paragraph 6, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a class with external linkage is defined in multiple translation units, all definitions must be identical. By including `foo.h` twice in different translation units with different values of `GOOD`, you've generated two different definitions of the class `foo`. This is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, and anything can happen.

The question you ask about "which" class definition is chosen does not make sense because a class does not "physically" exist inside the object files produced by translation. Instead, each translation unit that includes the class definition is compiled under the assumption that the class really does have that definition in every translation unit. When the translation units are linked together, something bad might happen if this assumption turns out to be incorrect.